# Compare HashMap with text file

Tags: java

I have a text file which contains field and values like "ID:987654 TYPE:Active ITEM:New.."
. Every line contains one item and different attribute. Now I want to compare this text file with HashMap which has already those values. What is the best way to compare them. How to read this text file and compare with HashMap. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How is your file formatted? Is it one item per line? Also, do you sometimes have spaces in the fields such as "ITEM:New Item with spaces". Last, how is you HashMap formatted? What is the key, what is the value? Is it ID as a key and an object containing TYPE and ITEM as the value? Elaborate so we can help you better.

Comment: Yes adam, HashMap<ID, arraylist> is in this format. Text file has space as well as ":" delimiter also. In text file every line is detail of one item

Answer (score 1):

Load the text file into another HashMap, using whatever semantics are appropriate, and then call HashMap.equals().

Answer (score 0):

Read the file using the java.util.Properties class. This will create a property object with a Hashtable. You are then able to iterate through the keys in your HashMap and do a comparision with the Hashtable.

This should be a starting point for an algorithm. Flesh the rest out yourself.

Comment: Thanks Brett. I am not sure how prpoerty works in java, I'll go thorough it. But I have one question. Will this create one entry in HashTable per line, I mean per unique ID, it will create an entry in HashTable. If you can help me further on this

Comment: Hashtable is very similar to HashMap. Read the documentation on this (http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html). Also read the documentation on properties.

Yes, if the the key (ID, TYPE, ITEM, ...) is unique (and one per line) then there will be one entry in the property hashtable per line in teh text file.

Comment: I tried Property from Java, but its loading only first item in prop, I am not bale to get any other value. Is there any other way to iterate through it?

Comment: java.util.Properties does not understand the syntax the OP specified.

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it to you to read the text file (unless I'm missing something, a class like BufferedReader should work for you), but I'll tell you how to use the HashMap.  Someone already provided the link to the documentation for it.  For each ID, you want to say something like

```
//do this for each ID you read - I'll suppose "id" is the ID and 
//"text" is the text (properties) associated with the ID on each iteration
//of some kind of loop here

    //search your HashMap for the id you just read
    String value = map.get(id);

    //if map doesn't contain ID
    if (value == null)
    {
        //do whatever you need to do in this case
    }
    //if it does contain it
    else
    {
        if (value.equals (text))
        {
            //the text file had the same thing as your existing HashMap
        }
        else
        {
            //had something else
        }
     }
```